# Preventing Firefox's Web Developer from Paying Attention to Ctrl+Shift+c (Not Firebug related)

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

In order to cut and paste in some web pages, such as Blackboard and Google Docs, I am forced to use `Ctrl+Shift+c` to copy elements. Unfortunately, this leads to problems since this shortcut is mapped to launcing Firefox's Web Developer Inspector window.

I have tried disabling the Web Developer in about:config settings by setting `devtools.enable.inspector` to `false`, but it doesn't change anything.

If anyone has suggestions, I'd appreciate them.

Comment: This ctrl+shift+c is hugely annoying for those of us who switch back and forth between copying from terminals (ctrl+shift+c) and firefox :-/